# Physics of Skiing

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am conducting a research paper on the physics of skiing, specifically how ski parameters affect the ski's ideal carve. I have come across [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0310086.pdf) paper, which is incredibly relevant but am having trouble deciphering its text. From the very start, chapter 2.1, they claim [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pLtr.jpg). How did they arrive at these conclusions? What math is going on here?

Comment: Taylor expansion around the minimum of any sufficiently smooth function.